# TYPO3 - user tries to delete a record in his limited language, can't do it because of the references

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I only found old entries to the topic, so I try to explain it:

We have a TYPO3 11.5.x with 8 languages, which 7 get translated via DeepL every night and only german is the main language. That's why we limit the language for our backend users to german. It is easier to grasp and maintain for them.

But now there is a huge problem. They can't delete, copy & paste or cut & paste the german record because of "1: Attempt to delete record without delete-permissions". I understand the reason for that but on the other hand, the have the right to delete the main language. The translated records are only references, the should be able to delete that. Is there a patch, a trick or a hack to it? Would gladly appreciate any idea.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you delete, copy & paste etc. E.g. for the copy-paste, do you expect only the default language to be copied? (the way you describe it, I would assume so, since translation is entirely handled automatically). However for cut-paste I would expect all languages to be affected. For deleted I would expect all languages to be affected. This gets messy very fast. You might be able to hook into it, but is this the best concept because then you are not using TYPO3 as is intented.

Comment: I hoped that the translations get effected when the main language is deleted or moved/copied/cut but because the user doesn't have the permission for the other languages it doesn't work. But yeah, it is intended that way bei TYPO3 so I probably won't find a better solution then your hook down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to accomplish something by "working around" the implementation it might not be the best idea.

However, if you want to see if it is possible, you may be able to solve this using a DataHandler hook,

For these type of things I would recommend to step through with a debugger to understand how TYPO3 works internally. TYPO3 uses the DataHandler which considers permissions.

For example for the case of deletion you would have to check if the current user has permissions to delete the record / page / pages but ignore the permissions for the translations.

In `DataHandler::deleteAction` hook `processCmdmap_deleteAction` gets called before the deletion. So far, so good. But then you would have to check the permissions yourself in your hook **and** take care of the deletions of the translations.

(You can see that within the DataHandler permissions is always considered. To override it you have to take care of a lot of the functionality yourself. Not something I would recommend.)

If you don't want your editors to tamper with the translations, you might be able to solve that differently.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As you mentioned it, it sounds really dirty but I can atleast present that solution and strongly advise against it. I hoped for a "TYPO3-solution" but I guess that's really the only working idea.

Answer (score 2):

The references between the main language by its translations are the core concept of translation in TYPO3. So editors may never ever be able to delete the main language if they are not allowed to edit/delete the other languages because that way a restricted editor would be able to delete content he/she has no access to.

If you want to handle the main language and the translations separately you must create the translated content elements as copies using a different language each. But you won't be able to identify the parent element any longer. You'd have to implement your own logic to know which CE is the parent of which translations.

It's also possible, but not recommend, to have a branch in the page tree for each language. That way you can update each branches translation independently from the others. That too would require you to implement a custom logic.

Maybe you could also do it with workspaces. One for editing the content one for publishing the content including the generated translations. I cannot tell if that idea actually works because I've never really set up a workspace environment with TYPO3 yet.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the concept but than I would love to have edit/delete rights for the languages but a "not visible"-Button in Records. :D But I think there is no other way around then create a hook like @sybille-peters said or activate all languages - thank you anyway! Or to find workarounds which is the way we are going: delete the hidden records after 30 days for example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe able to do it as system administrator?

In typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php you add user id's 1 and 2 for example:

```
'SYS' => [
   'systemMaintainers' => [
        1,
        2,
    ],
],
```

Comment: That was a nice idea! But it didn't work. Same problem: "1: Attempt to delete record without delete-permissions". Which is true, I try to delete languages without permission for them but the user has the permission for the mainlanguage. Every other is only a reference to the main language.